# EF 5.0 Model First - How To Make Not Mapped Properties

Tags: entity-framework-5

Code First has the attribute [NotMapped] for properties which are not to be mapped: how would one achieve the same thing in model-first mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NotMapped` properties are not part of your mapping. When the model first approach is used EDMX represents the mapping so every property defined in the diagram is mapped. If you want to have non-mapped property it must not be defined in the diagram. All classes generated by EF's code generation are partial so you only need to create your own partial part of the class (it must be in the same namespace and assembly as generated part) and define your non-mapped property in code.

Comment: But is there a way to duplicate `NotMapped` to the extent that relationships you delete in your edmx are *never* reapplied when you chose "Update Model from Database..."? If I update, all those relationships that I can about in the database, but not in the EF models, are back.

Comment: Deleting an attribute from the EDMX file, still results it in showing up on an INSERT it just inserts NULL. What do we do if we dont want it on an insert?

Comment: @n00b: EDMX has three internal models. If the attribute is still in your inserts, it most probably exists in storage model.